# Openvino xml file graph output shape not as expected

Tags: openvino

I've been trying to reshape to NCHW format using tf.keras.layers.Reshape function but the final xml file outputs this :

There's a Transpose layer after reshaping to (1,6,26,26) and final shape is (1,26,6,26)
I'm not sure why there's a Transpose layer , I want the shapes to be (1,6,26,26)

What's the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you need to understand the topology of your model's network. Then you can reshape and batch.

You can use the model optimizer to manipulate your input size.
This is how you can do it: [Model Optimizer Advanced Reshape, Batching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ga8j0lgi-OQ)